# AWS S3 Java SDK: When does the file actually begin download

Tags: java, amazon-s3

When does the content of the file I am retrieving actually begin downloading from S3?

```
AmazonS3Client.getObject()

S3Object.getContent()

S3ObjectInputStream.read()
```

From what I can tell, it's the first one, but I haven't found the answer explicitly in the docs

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "begin downloading."

Technically, it's `getObject()`.  Otherwise it wouldn't throw the exceptions it throws, some of which necessarily require that the service has been contacted and the download initiated (or failed or denied).

> Be extremely careful when using this method; the returned Amazon S3 object contains a direct stream of data from the HTTP connection.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-

The download must have already started, for the stream to be available. Bytes are waiting... but you are sitting on a stream that you haven't read from, beyond the response headers... so the download is stalled from proceeding further until you start reading.